# "not a valid month"-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE MRE_BUDGET as (
   select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date as start_date, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((LEAD(Rental_date) over (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date)), 'YYYYMMDD')-1, 'YYYYMMDD') as end_date, Rate  
   from (select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date, Avg(RATE) as RATE from mre_competitor_data1 where competitor='BUDGET' group by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date)
   where rental_date <= (select cpd from mre_system_parameters));
```

and the error says "**not a valid month**"... I need to remove the dates that don't have a valid month? Not sure how to do that??

Comment: In a comment on your previous question you said that `cpd` was a number; so what data type is `rental_date`? Is it a real date - as it should be - in which case why compare it with a number? And if `rental_date` is also a number (or a string), why? The error would then mean that you have values in there which cannot be converted to actual dates. This is why you should use the correct data type - store dates *as dates*. 'Removing' those would then make slightly more sense, but throwing away data because you didn't store it properly isn't a good situation...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  My guess is that `cpd` is the problem.

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a VARCHAR column to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to remove the dates that don't have a valid month?

Your source table data doesn't have dates with in valid months - that's (nearly) impossible when using the right data types. The error is coming from implicit conversions that are creating strings in one format, followed explicit conversions back to dates using a different format.

You are currently doing:

```
 TO_CHAR(
   TO_DATE(
     (LEAD(Rental_date) over (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size
        order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date)),
     'YYYYMMDD'
   )-1,
   'YYYYMMDD'
 ) as end_date,
```

As `rental_date` is (hopefully) a date column, passing it - regardless of the `lead()` - into `to_date()` means you're really doing:

```
 TO_CHAR(
   TO_DATE(
     TO_CHAR(
       LEAD(Rental_date) over (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size
         order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date)m
       <your_current_NLS_DATE_FORMAT>,
      ),
     'YYYYMMDD'
   )-1,
   'YYYYMMDD'
 ) as end_date,
```

with your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` not matching the formats you use explcitly later. As an equally-contrived example with a fixed date:

```
select
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(
        date '2019-02-28',
        'DD-MM-YYYY' -- guessing your NLS_DATE_FORMAT
      ),
      'YYYYMMDD'
     ) -1,
    'YYYYMMDD'
  )
from dual;

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

You might just have your `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` the wrong way around:

```
select
  TO_DATE(
    TO_CHAR(
      date '2019-02-28',
      'YYYYMMDD'
     ) -1,
    'YYYYMMDD'
  )
from dual;

TO_DATE(TO
----------
2019-02-27
```

but I'm not sure why you're converting the value at all when you can just do:

```
select date '2019-02-28' - 1
from dual;

DATE'2019-
----------
2019-02-27
```

or in your case:

```
LEAD(Rental_date) over (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size
  order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date) - 1 as end_date
```

which in situ, with redundant parentheses removed, might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE MRE_BUDGET as
select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date as start_date,
  LEAD(Rental_date) over (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size
    order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date) - 1 as end_date,
  Rate  
from (
  select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date, Avg(RATE) as RATE
  from mre_competitor_data1
  where competitor='BUDGET'
  group by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date
)
where rental_date <= (select cpd from mre_system_parameters));
```

Comment: If `rental_date` is actually a number or string then this is largely irrelevant... will update or delete once the actual data types have been established *8-)